# Notepad++ Move text between double square brackets to end of line for non standard line pattern

Tags: notepad++

So I have a script, with lines separated by a carriage return. Sometimes the writer messes up and puts notes (text contained within [[]]) in the middle or beginning of the line when it should be at the end of it. Because this is not uniform, I've had some trouble finding a way to move these notes to be at the end of the line they appeared on within Notepad++ automatically, either via a macro or some fancy regex find & replace.

Simply, I want an automated way fo going from this:

```
hello [[emphasis]] my friends!
[[laugh]] how are you?
```

to:

```
hello my friends! [[emphasis]]
how are you? [[laugh]]
```

Comment: don't we need "hello" in the first line?

Comment: @msp9011 woops, that's a typo. You are correct

Comment: Is using excel to solve this allowable? || If can, you may combine MID(),FIND(),and SUBSTITUTE() to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the **Replace** dialog:

- Find What = `(?-s)(\[\[.*\]\])[\h]*(.*?)[\h]*$`
- Replace With = `$2 $1`
- Search Mode = Regular Expression

Basically, I search for `[[...]]` and put it in `$1`, then everything after it goes in `$2`. It then replaces those two such that the `$2` goes after `$1`.  I do some extra things, like making sure it ignores `. matches newlines`, so that `.*` won't wrap across lines

FYI: If you have further search-and-replace ("matching", "marking", "bookmarking", regular expression, "regex") needs, study [this FAQ at the Notepad++ Community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation) and the documentation it points to.  It will help you with using regular expressions in Notepad++, and will help you understand the details of the regex I've written.